# PHP: How to delete a cookie with onclick event from button

Tags: php, forms, button, cookies, unset

I'm trying to create a sign out button with php. I might be going about this the completely wrong way, but anyhow I'm trying to delete a cookie on the click of a button.

```
    <?php 
    function logOut() {
        setcookie('userDetails[username]',"", time()-1200);
    }



if(isset($_COOKIE["userDetails"])) {
    echo "<table id='rtgLoginBox'>" ;
        echo "<tr>" ;
            echo "<td> Cookie " . $_COOKIE["userDetails"]["username"] . "!";
            echo "<td></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td><input id='rtgLoginBtn' type='submit' value='Log Out' onclick=\"logOut();\" /></td>" ;
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
        echo "</tr>" ;
    echo "</table>" ;
} else {
    echo "<table id='rtgLoginBox'>" ;
        echo "<tr>" ;
            echo "<td><form action='process.php' method='post'>Username:</td>" ;
            echo "<td><input name='usernamein' id='rtgUsernameTxt' type='text' size='20' class='rtgSignUpTxt'/></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td>Password:</td>" ;
            echo "<td><input name='passwordin' id='rtgPasswordTxt' type='password' size='20' class='rtgSignUpTxt' /></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td><input id='rtgLoginBtn' type='submit' value='Log In' />  </form><input id='rtgLoginBtn' type='submit' value='Sign Up' onclick=\"location.href='SignUp.php'\" /></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td><a href='mysite.com'><p style='padding:0 !important;'>Forgot Login Details?</p></a></td>" ;
        echo "</tr>" ;
    echo "</table>" ;
    }

    ?>
```

As far as I've read online, this should work? I also tried putting the function under the echoed table, but this didn't work either.

Comment: PHP is not a event driven language

Comment: How would I go about bridging the gap then, so a log out button would unset a cookie?

Comment: The problem is that while you're setting the cookie to a negative time to wipe it out the way you should, headers haven't been sent to the browser before you're trying to further process based upon the cookie. Just unset the cookie. `unset($_COOKIE['userDetails'])`

Comment: @MetalFrog, how would I write that?

Would sending user to a redirect logout page work?

Comment: I just gave you the code in my comment. Put that right after your `setcookie`... Also, I think John is onto someting as well. Are you actually calling your logout function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will cause the person to logout if they press the logout button and then redirect them to a new page called whatever.php. You obviously can change that to be whatever you want.

```
<?php 
    function logOut() {
        setcookie('userDetails[username]',"", time()-1200);
        unset($_COOKIE['userDetails']);
    }

if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    logOut();
    header('Location: /whatever.php');
    exit;
}

if(isset($_COOKIE["userDetails"])) {
    echo "<form action='".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'><table id='rtgLoginBox'>" ;
        echo "<tr>" ;
            echo "<td> Cookie " . $_COOKIE["userDetails"]["username"] . "!";
            echo "<td></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td><input id='rtgLoginBtn' type='submit' value='Log Out' /></td>" ;
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
        echo "</tr>" ;
    echo "</table></form>" ;
} else {
    echo "<table id='rtgLoginBox'>" ;
        echo "<tr>" ;
            echo "<td><form action='process.php' method='post'>Username:</td>" ;
            echo "<td><input name='usernamein' id='rtgUsernameTxt' type='text' size='20' class='rtgSignUpTxt'/></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td>Password:</td>" ;
            echo "<td><input name='passwordin' id='rtgPasswordTxt' type='password' size='20' class='rtgSignUpTxt' /></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td><input id='rtgLoginBtn' type='submit' value='Log In' />  </form><input id='rtgLoginBtn' type='submit' value='Sign Up' onclick=\"location.href='SignUp.php'\" /></td>" ;
        echo "</tr><tr>" ;
            echo "<td></td>" ;
            echo "<td><a href='mysite.com'><p style='padding:0 !important;'>Forgot Login Details?</p></a></td>" ;
        echo "</tr>" ;
    echo "</table>" ;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying "onclick='logOut()'",you are calling function logOut() from javascript, not php....

We may think programs are always interactive, and we can always call some sort of function as something happens, but php does not work like that...to understand this you should know about the browser/server model more.

As someone requires a php page, e.g, index.php, the server gets the requirement and look for index.php on its disk according to the URL you gave it....then it interprets the entire php file into html and transfer the html document to the browser....so the one in front of the screen recieves no longer php codes, but static HTML document...

If you want to make a page interactive, insert javaScript into your webpage, javascript is tranfered to the browser in plain text, and it works in the browser, not on the server.

so a website uses both js and php, php is used to deal with server-side works like querying databases and managing the whole website...and javascript works on pages..

so if you want to change or remove cookies interactively, what you need is javascript, you can declare a "logOut()" function in javascript, and control the cookies with that....or if you really want to control the cookie with php, use js to pass the command through ajax to some php file, and delete the cookie in php.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a weird, but effective, solution to this problem. The issue is that you cant call a php function, true, but you can invoke a POST to PHP by adding a HIDDEN Input box to the form with a value of "whatever", then use the onclick event of the button to change that value to something like "cut". Then check for the value of the key = "cut" upon invoking the POST method. You may not be able to change the value back to "notCut" with this procedure, but if you were creative enough, you could set a timer that changes the value back to "notCut" every so often... Tested this myself and it works great!

```
<?php 
 if (array_key_exists('cutter', $_POST)) {
            if ($_POST["cutter"] == 'cut') {
            setcookie("yourCookie", "cookie", time() - 60 * 60);
            echo "You ate the cookie!";
        }
        }
?>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="cutter" name="cutter" value="NOTcut" hidden="true">
        <input id='cutter' type="submit" value="Cookie Cutter" onclick="document.getElementById('cutter').value='cut'">
    </form>
```